# dependency of a JNI DLL which internally calls another dll

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I have created a JNI library with visual studio to use in java application and internally this dll calls another DLL (openssl). Now when i load this library with eclipse I get an error saying "Can't find dependent libraries" unless I put the path of the other DLL on the PATH variable.

```
in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\*****\jniDLL.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at iwinAlgTest.test.<clinit>(test.java:7)
```

And I've already tried adding it to -Djava.library.path and to the classpath, and i also included all of my dll and openssl dll and lib files like libeay32.lib but neither worked. Is there a way to do this?
I tried to use Dependency Walker to check if there are any files required by my jniDLL.dll
but i get interesting thing:
what i really do to create my jniDLL:

```
(jniDLL --> calls myDLL.dll)  ==> (myDLL.dll --> calls openssl library)
```

but Dependency Walker says that

```
(jniDLL --> depends on myDLL.exe) not myDLL.dll
```

Note : at first it was a win32 application( which output myDLL.exe) but i changed the project setting to output myDLL.dll then i create another project to create a JNI dll from myDLL.dll which i wrote in c++

Comment: `and lib files like libeay32.lib` Library files are not used at run time.  They are used only in the build process.  Add the DLL's to a path specified by your PATH environment variable and see if that solves the issue.  If you add a new directory to your PATH, then you may need to restart Eclipse for the effect to take place.

Answer (score 1):

One way to bypass this is to load your openssl.dll prior to loading myDLL, so myDLL will find the symbols loaded when it tries to initiate .

Other ways to go around this :

- add the openssl.dll to PATH (you already mentioned this)
- copy openssl in system32 at install time
- put openssl in the same folder as your executable path

This however will only work on Windows.

In linux, you will have to change the rpath inside the .so (but I believe this is out of scope).